# Titanium Studio Error: when I run the the default mobile project with Android emulator

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, compiler-errors, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on windows 7, 64-bit home basic and I managed to install Titanium Studio, build: 2.1.2.201208301612,  somehow. I just followed the quick starter guide provided by the appcelerator and installed everything.

Please check these images: [programs that I installed](http://thedezinetree.com/titanium_bugs/)

but when I tried to run the default program(app.js) on the android emulator I'm getting bunch of errors.

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\SA\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\helloworld\build.log<br>
[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment
[INFO][Vold    (   29)] Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up<br>
[INFO][Netd    (   30)] Netd 1.0 starting<br>
[WARN][Vold    (   29)] No UMS switch available<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back<br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] received: <br>
[INFO][qemu-props(   52)] invalid format, ignored.<br>
[INFO][        (   34)] ServiceManager: 0xacd0<br>
[INFO][CameraService(   34)] CameraService started: pid=34<br>
[INFO][AudioFlinger(   34)] AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3f0 ready to run<br>
[INFO][SamplingProfilerIntegration(   33)] Profiler is disabled.<br>
[INFO][Zygote  (   33)] Preloading classes...<br>
[ERROR][Zygote  (   33)] setreuid() failed. errno: 2<br>
[WARN][MediaProfiles(   33)] could not find media config xml file<br>
[INFO][Zygote  (   33)] ...preloaded 1265 classes in 10083ms.<br>
[ERROR][Zygote  (   33)] setreuid() failed. errno: 17<br>
[INFO][Zygote  (   33)] Preloading resources.....a huge list of errors
```

(please check the [last screenshot](http://thedezinetree.com/titanium_bugs/) here)

I'm new to mobile development. I tried to find all sources but couldn't figureout the problem. Can any one please help me!!!

Comment: You'll need to upload the complete error log somewhere, like gist.github.com or pastebin. Just looking at your paths, it's possible that spaces to your Android SDK or to your app are a problem. Or 64-bit JVM may be a problem. Without the full log, I can only guess.

Comment: Hi, Here is the [error log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=994esDwF)

Comment: are there same errors which you showed at previous comment or changed? And have you set path for "titanium sdk home" AND "Android SDK home" at "titanium studio->windows->preferences->titanium studio->titanium"

Answer (score 0):

you have installed jdk 7 with 64 bits. i think titanium supports 32 bit jdk 6 only. see more details at [Setting up titanium studio](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio-section-30086257_SettingupTitaniumStudio-OracleJDK)

they have mentioned that "**32bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of whether Titanium is running on a 32bit or 64bit Windows system**"

Comment: As it said in the documentation I have installed 'jdk-7u7-windows-i586.exe'. But finally the programs are running in the emulator after play around with 'JDK Path' by following this [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkycwpimOEc&feature=related) and restarting few times. But the huge list of errors are still there, I'm not sure why :(

Comment: have you set path for "titanium sdk home" at "titanium studio->windows->preference->titanium studio->titanium"??